# SQL Always on Availability Groups Direct Seeding

Tags: availability-groups, aws, high-availability, sql-server-2019

Setting up a new SQL cluster and HA using SQL Availability Groups.

1. SQL 2019 STD 2 Node Multi Subnet Basic AG
2. Primary Node AWS
3. Secondary Node VMWare on premise

I am using the newer Automatic Seeding option to replicate the database from the primary to secondary.  When looking at the DMV sys.dm_hadr_physical_seeding_stats the transfer_rate_MB_per_Second starts quickly then drops down to 0 mb/sec and the seed takes hours for a 4GB database.

I have switched on the trace flag 9567 for compression but this doesn't seemed to have helped.  My network and VMware engineers have investigated and cannot see any issues, a standard SMB copy between servers works as expected.

Are there additional settings required in AWS for this process or something we may have missed, any help appreciated.

Comment: How long does it stay quick for?...a half hour? I recall AWS (depending on your instance type) had some limitations where the first half hour of I/O was quick and then throttled after, ever 24 hours.

Comment: hi JD, its quick for a matter of seconds just as the transfer starts then it drops down to 0 within the first 1/2 mins

Comment: Have you tried seeding an empty database to see if there's a difference in behavior? Or initializing via backup/restore? Testing those questions would help answer if you're having a specific problem with automatic seeding, or a larger problem with network connectivity between servers

Comment: Morning AMtwo my job this morning is to do exactly that I am going to try with the older backup / restore process.  We do have a test setup for HA which works well but that is totally only premise so no AWS which is where we suspect the issue lies.  Thanks for your suggestions.